# Merge many arrays in one array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 3 arrays like this

```
a = [1,1,1];
b = [2,2,2];
c = [3,3,3];
```

I want to merge all this arrays in one array so that the result should be this

```
d = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3];
```

I have created a function that does this :

```
function Merge()
{
    var result = [];
    var maxLength = 0;
    for(key in arguments)
        if(arguments[key].length>maxLength)
            maxLength = arguments[key].length;
    while(maxLength--)
        for(key in arguments)
            if(x=arguments[key].shift())
                result.push(x);
    return result;
}
```

The problem is when I call the function `Merge` like this

```
d = Merge(a,b,c);
```

it returns the correct array to the `d` variable but when I try to print what's in `a,b,c` I find all of them are empty arrays, because I used `shift()`.

Then I correct this bug by copying the value of `arguments` to another array and work with that array

```
function Merge()
{
    var result = [];
    var maxLength = 0;
    var arg = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arguments));
    for(key in arg)
        if(arg[key].length>maxLength)
            maxLength = arg[key].length;
    while(maxLength--)
        for(key in arg)
            if(x=arg[key].shift())
                result.push(x);
    return result;
}
```

**First question :** what I couldn't understand is that why I shift on the `arguments` array and changes the `a,b,c`.

**Second question :** is there a simple way to do this ?

Comment: You should test to see what the value of `x` really is. `x=arguments[key].shift()` because it clearly isn't what you think it is.

Comment: it is the value of the shifted element from the array, when the array is empty , shift returns undefined

Comment: Would all arrays that are being merged be the same size?

Comment: no, if `a=[1,1,1,1]; b=[2,2,2]; c=[3,3];` the result should be `d=[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,1];` the function I have defined does it correctly because i test on x if it's undefined

Comment: So then what's the issue?

Comment: have read the post?? I wrote with bold text first question, seconde question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question

> Array.prototype.shift() method removes the first element from an array
>   and returns that element. This method changes the length of the array.
>   (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

This function will merge n arrays without modifying them.

```
function merge(){
   var result = [],
       lengths = [],
       max_len,
       num_args = arguments.length;

    for( i = 0; i < num_args; i++ ) {
        lengths.push( arguments[ i ].length );
    }
    max_len = Math.max.apply( null, lengths );

    for( i = 0; i < max_len; i++ ){
        for( j = 0; j < num_args; j++ ) {
            if( arguments[ j ][ i ] != null ) {
                result.push( arguments[ j ][ i ] );
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: this function returns `[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]` , but it returns the correct answer when I changed `i` and `j` in `result.push( arguments[ j ][ i ] );`. I think it wouldn't work for arrays with different sizes

Comment: Oh, I didn't closely read your initial question, my bad.  It doesn't give your desired answer, and your change would definitely not work for arrays of different sizes.

Comment: @Khalid Okay, updated this with a working solution for variable-length input.

Answer (score 0):

It is the *purpose* of shift to alter the shifted array.  Use an ordinary index to step through the array:

```
for (var i=0; i<arg.length; i++) { result.push(arg[i]); }
```

Comment: didn't work for me because I realized that `args` isn't a real array, it's an object with indexes `0,1,2..` which means, it doesn't have the property `length`

Comment: @Khalid You're right that arguments isn't a native array, but it most definitely has a `length` property.

Comment: @Waxen let's suppose it has a property `length`. this solution wouldn't work, it will return `[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]` while it should be `[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]`

Comment: @Khalid Agreed, I was simply pointing out that `arguments` does indeed have a `length` property.

Comment: @Waxen, you're right, in this case no need to args, only arguments, but it wouldn't solve the problem